# Limpeza do buffer do teclado após scanf

Tags: c, scanf, teclado, buffer

Estou tendo problemas com a função **`scanf();`**. Ao efetuar a leitura de dois ou mais valores, os valores posteriores não são lidos.

Eu já tentei:

```
__fpurge(stdin);
```

Após efetuar as leituras, mas, neste caso, preciso dar um enter depois de cada leitura, o que é um pouco incômodo para mim.

Também já tentei:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Mas não resolve (Estou usando Debian 7.1, creio que o **`fflush(stdin);`** só funcione em Windows)

O que me solucionou o problema foi:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Limpa o buffer do teclado
void flush_in(){ 
    int ch;
    while( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){} 
}

int main(){
    char c;

    printf("\nEntre com um caractere: ");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    flush_in(); 
    printf("\nO caractere: \"%c\" tem o valor ASCII %d", c ,(int)c);

    printf("\nEntre com um caractere: ");  
    scanf("%c",&c);
    flush_in();  
    //__fpurge ( stdin );
    printf("\nO caractere: \"%c\" tem o valor ASCII %d", c ,(int)c);

    printf("\nPress any key to exit...\n\n"); 
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Mas o código da função **`flush_in()`**, que obtive **[aqui](http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/LaproI/Fflush/CorrigeScanfGets.html)**, é obscuro para mim.

Então...

1. Porque este problema ocorre?
2. Como solucionar este problema de forma que o mesmo código funcione em ambientes Windows e Linux após ser compilado?
3. O que faz o trecho de código a seguir?

   ```
   void flush_in(){
       int ch;
       while( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){}
   }
   ```

Comment: Perdoe-me a formatação. Não conseguir formatar o último trecho de código. Também não consegui colocar "flush_in();" em negrito e itálico. Se alguém ver, por favor, edite.

Comment: Porque quando se lê um único caractere o terminador (gerado pelo ENTER) continua no buffer. A função despreza este caractere. Note que existem outras maneiras de se desprezar esta "sujeira" do buffer de entrada, por exemplo infoemndo na leitura seguinte que deve desprezar um eventual '\n' presente no buffer de entrada.

Comment: Corrigi a formatação daquele último bloco. Para formatar blocos de código dentro de itens de lista, é preciso dobrar a indentação.

Comment: Obrigado o/ Eu não estava conseguindo colocar. 
O título e as tags melhoraram bastante também.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O problema é que quando você digita o seguinte:

```
A [enter]
B [enter]
```

Foi inserido no buffer de entrada o seguinte:

```
A\nB\n
```

Quando executa `scanf("%c", &c)` você lê um único caractere do buffer. No caso é `A`.

```
\nB\n
```

Repare que em momento nenhum o `\n` foi consumido. No próximo `scanf("%c", &c)`, ele será lido. Então `c = '\n'` e o buffer é:

```
B\n
```

E aqui mora o erro. O comportamento esperado era ter lido `A` na primeira e `B` na segunda.

A correção para isso, no entanto, é bem simples e não precisa de nenhuma função adicional. Simplesmente consuma a quebra de linha! Use `scanf("%c\n", &c)`.

Quanto a o que a função `flush_in` faz, observe:

```
void flush_in() {
    int ch;
    do {
        ch = fgetc(stdin)
    } while (ch != EOF && ch != '\n');
}
```

Ela vai repetitivamente ler o buffer de entrada até encontrar uma quebra de linha ou até que o buffer acabe. Ou seja, vai consumir toda a linha atual.

Comment: O EOF (-1), de que forma ele funciona? Poderia me explicar mais a respeito?

Comment: Quando lendo de uma stream que possa ser finalizada e não há mais nada para ler, uma operação de leitura vai retornar `EOF`. No caso do `stdin`, você pode apertar `Ctrl+D` no terminal para fechar a stream (qualquer tentativa de leitura vai resultar em `EOF` em vez de bloquear esperando o usuário digitar algo). No caso do `flush_in` está ai para evitar um loop infinito (já que a leitura ficaria eternamente retornando `EOF`).

Comment: Não é pouco performático ler cada caracter individualmente? Tenho a impressão que é mais eficiente usar a solução do `fgets' proposta pelo @pmg

Answer (score 5):

A melhor (sem falhas, compativel com todos os sistemas) maneira de ler input do utilizador é utilizar unicamente `fgets()` para obter dados (nao misturar com `scanf()`, `getchar()`, ou outras funcoes de leitura).

Cada vez que se faz um `fgets()` deve-se verificar se se leu uma linha completa (o ultimo elemento da string lida é `'\n'`) e, caso contrario, continuar a ler aumentando o tamanho do buffer ou ignorando os caracteres extra.

Depois da linha completa ter sido obtida (e o `'\n'` final removido se se quiser) deve-se tratar essa linha com `sscanf()`, `strstr()`, `strtol()`, `strtod()`, acesso directo aos caracteres, ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[80];

    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        printf("Entre com um caractere: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
        if (buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] != '\n') {
            // linha muito longa, ignorar o resto usando a parte final do buffer
            do {
                fgets(buffer + 1, sizeof buffer - 1, stdin);
            } while (buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] != '\n');
        }
        printf("O caractere: \"%c\" tem o valor ASCII %d\n", *buffer, *buffer);
    }

    printf("Press ENTER to exit...\n");
    do {
        fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
    } while (buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] != '\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char c;

   printf("\nEntre com um caracter: ");
   scanf(" %c%*[^\n]",&c);
   printf("\nO caracter: \"%c\" tem o valor ASCII %d", c ,(int)c);

   printf("\nEntre com um caracter: ");
   scanf(" %c%*[^\n]",&c);
   printf("\nO caracter: \"%c\" tem o valor ASCII %d", c ,(int)c);

   printf("\nPress any key to exit...\n\n");
   getchar(); // consome '\n' deixado plo scanf
   getchar(); // aguarda ENTER do teclado
}
```

Explicação de `scanf(" %c%*[^\n]",&c);`:

1. pula whitespace (entre os quais ' ', '\t' e '\n')
2. lê um caracter X que não é whitespace
3. pula todos os caracteres até achar um '\n' (o '\n' fica no buffer)

No próximo `scanf` o '\n' que ficou no buffer vai ser consumido no passo 1.

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser usado este código aqui que também funciona perfeito:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Há várias maneiras de limpar o *buffer* (área de armazenamento temporário) do teclado.
A mais indicada é, com certeza, a seguinte e já mencionada. É a mais recomendada por ser prática, simples e portátil (funciona em mais de um sistema operacional).

`void clear_keyboard_buffer(void)
{
    int c = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
    return;
}`

Como já foi explicado, esse código consome, limpa, zera o *buffer*.

Comment: para consumir o restante do  buffer é só fazer: "scanf("%*[^\n]");", não precisa do loop; no próximo scanf o "\n" que ficou no vai ser consumido pelos formatos "%s", "%d", etc; no caso do formato "%c", ao se colocar um espaço antes do formato todos os epaços e cr/lf são consumidos, assim: "scanf(" %c", &ch);"...em minha resposta dou um exemplo completo

Answer (score 0):

Conforme mencionado pelo Guilherme Bernal, sempre que é lido um char com `scanf("%c", &x);` temos esse problema. Uma forma prática de resolver é dar um `getchar()` após a leitura, ficando:

```
scanf("%c", &x);
getchar();
```

Ainda assim, a forma mais segura de tratar esse tipo de problema é com fgets(), conforme mencionado pelo @pmg.