# comparação usando caracteres em c

Tags: c, loop, char

Ok, o problema so esta na função q31 e na q311.

http://pastebin.com/8CJwKej4

Deixei o codigo completo no link acima.

então aqui esta funçao q311:

```
void q311(){
char forma;
int n,jota,b,i,j;
printf("Informe a figura e o tamanho: ");
scanf("%c",&forma);
scanf("%i",&n);
    if (forma=='q')
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
        printf("*");
            for ( b = 1; b < n; ++b)
            {
                if ((i==jota)|| (i==0))
                {
                    printf("*");
                }
                else if (b==jota)
                {
                    printf("*");
                }
                else
                    printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
            }
        }
    else if (forma=='t')
    {
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            {
             if(i==n-1 || j==0 ||i==j)
                 printf("*");
              else
                printf(" ");
        }
          printf("\n");      
         }
    }
    else
        printf("Forma Invalida\n");

}
```

O meu programa sempre da como saída "Forma Invalida" mesmo que voce digite "t" ou "q"... Queria saber por que isso esta acontecendo.

Comment: Eu executei a função postada como um programa e funcionou certinho. A comparação de caracteres que está fazendo está certa. Pode ser lixo, tente usar `fflush(stdin)` antes do `printf`.

Comment: qual printf? o primeiro?

Comment: voce acha que a string esta com valor de lixo?

Comment: Sim pode acontecer, afinal você tem um programa grande com várias funções. Tente usar o comando antes do primeiro `printf`. Tente executar a função isoladamente como eu fiz e depois conte-me o resultado.

Comment: Estranho! Realmente funciona ...

Comment: Mas nao tem como resolver para o programa grande?

Comment: O `fflush(stdin)` não resolveu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que ocorre é que `stdin` está com o caractere que você tinha digitado na função principal para escolher a função `q311`, um "enter". E um enter realmente não é um "t" ou um "q".

A forma mais simples de corrigir isso é fazendo com que o `scanf` ignore o "enter" acrescentando um espaço antes do tipo:

```
scanf(" %c",&forma);
```

Recomendo duas leituras:

Uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9427/limpeza-do-buffer-do-teclado-ap%C3%B3s-scanf) nossa.

Um [material](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2012/12/Buffer--o-que-e-como-limpar-e-as-funcoes-fflush-e-fpurge.html) externo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, o fflush(stdin) não tinha funcionado.