# Mesmo usando fflush, a função fscanf não está funcionando

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
struct cadastro{
    char nome[30];
    float notas[1][4];
    int faltas;
}alunos[3];

void LimpaTela(){//função para limpar a tela
    system("cls");
}

void incluir(struct cadastro inclusao[]){
    FILE *arq;

    printf("\tFaça o cadastro dos alunos...\n");
    arq = fopen("arquivo.txt", "w");
    fprintf(arq, "%s", "Nomes dos alunos...\n");
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("Inf. o nome: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(inclusao[i].nome, 30, stdin);
        fprintf(arq, "%s",inclusao[i].nome);
        for(j=0;j<1;j++){
            for(k=0;k<4;k++){
                printf("Inf. as notas: ");
                fflush(stdin);
                fscanf(arq, "%d" ,&inclusao[i].notas[j][k]);
                fprintf(arq, "%d",inclusao[i].notas[j][k]);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(arq);    
}

int menu(){//funcao para o menu do trabalho
    int escolha;
    printf("1) Limpar o conteudo do arquivo TXT\n");
    printf("2) Incluir conteudo do arquivo TXT\n");
    printf("3) Sair\n");
    printf("O que deseja fazer? ");
    scanf("%d",&escolha);
    int *ptr=&escolha;
    return *ptr;
}

int main(){ 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int menu1, contador_saida=0;
    char ch;

    LimpaTela();
    menu1 = menu();
    switch(menu1){
        case 2:
            LimpaTela();
            incluir(alunos);
        break;
    }
    printf("\nSaindo...\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você provavelmente está esperando que `fflush(stdin)` limpe seu fluxo de entrada de quaisquer caracteres que sobraram nele da última entrada, mas o [`fflush`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) foi feito para limpar apenas **fluxos de saída**.

O comportamento do `fflush` quando recebe como parâmetro um fluxo de entrada é dependente da implementação. Algumas implementações vão limpar um fluxo de entrada também, mas esse comportamento não é portável e você não deve confiar na existência dele.

Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9429/26404) para uma solução para o seu problema que não envolve `fflush(stdin)`.