# Tamanho de vetor em C

Tags: c, array, struct

Sou novo na linguagem C e estou obtendo problemas para determinar o tamanho de vetores do tipo struct.

Exemplo. Tenho uma estrutura do tipo categoria com três tipos de variáveis 1 int e 2 char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct categoria_st{
    char nome_categ[25];
    int num_subcateg;
    char subcateg_st
};
```

Agora, eu pretendo criar um vetor dinâmico do tipo struct `categorias_st` através de uma pergunta dentro da função main. Pensei em algo do tipo:

```
int main(){
struct categoria_st cat;
int n_categ;



   printf("Quantas categorias queres adicionar?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n_categ);
    return 0;

}
```

Contudo, eu não sei como realizar isso na linguagem C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Não sou a melhor pessoa para responder, mas estou aprendendo com isso.

Abaixo passo a passo de um exemplo que estava testando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LongFlickeringDiamondbackrattlesnake)

Primeiro criamos a `struct` aqui o identificador é **s_produtos**

```
struct s_produtos
{
  int codigo;
  char nome[20];
};
```

Definimos duas variáveis do tipo `int`

```
// Recebera o valor informado pelo usuário
int qnt = 0;
// A cada loop guardara a posição no qual sera adicionado
// o produto
int posicao = 0;
```

Lê a entrada do teclado e armazena o valor informado em `qnt`

```
printf("Quantas produtos deseja adicionar?:");
scanf(" %d", &qnt);
```

Criamos a variável `protudos` do tipo `s_produtos` e definimos seu tamanho com o valor de `qnt`

```
struct s_produtos produtos[qnt];
```

Fazemos o loop e é pedido ao usuário informar os dados.

```
for(posicao; posicao < qnt; posicao++) {
  printf("\n");
  printf("Informe o código:");
  scanf("%d", &produtos[posicao].codigo);
  flush_in();// Limpa o teclado
  printf("Informe o nome:");
  // Usei gets pois scanf para no espaço e não pega a linha toda, ex:
  // Leite em Pó
  // Só retorna: Leite
  gets(produtos[posicao].nome);

}
```

A função `flush_in` encontrei no [***SOpt***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9429/60376) pois `scanf(" %d", &produtos[posicao].codigo);` não estava funcionando.

```
void flush_in() {
    int ch;
    do {
        ch = fgetc(stdin)
    } while (ch != EOF && ch != '\n');
}
```

Abaixo exibimos os registros na tela

```
// Armazena o tamanho total do vetor
int total = sizeof(produtos)/sizeof(produtos[0]);
printf("\n\n");
printf("+--------- PRODUTOS ---------+\n");
for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  printf("%d - %s\n", produtos[i].codigo, produtos[i].nome);
}
printf("+----------------------------+\n");
```

> Podes ver funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LongFlickeringDiamondbackrattlesnake).

#### Referência

- [Limpeza do buffer do teclado após scanf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9427)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct categoria_st{
  char nome_categ[25];
  int num_subcateg;
  char subcateg_st;
}

int main(){
  int n_categ;
  //primeiro pedir ao utilizador o numero de categorias
  printf("Quantas categorias queres adicionar?\n");
  scanf("%d", &n_categ);

  //neste momento já podes declarar a variável do tipo da estrutura definida
  //com o valor pretendido pelo utilizador
  struct categoria_st category[n_categ];

  return 0;

}
```

Inicialmente é criada uma estrutura chamada `categoria_st`, constituída por 3 variáveis `nome_categ`, `num_subcateg`, `subcateg_st`.

No `main` é declarada uma variável `n_categ` do tipo inteiro para guardar o tamanho das categorias a inserir.

Esse valor é guardado no endereço da variável `n_categ` através do `scanf()`.

De seguida é então declarado um `array` da estrutura chamada *category* com o tamanho inserido pelo utilizador.

Comment: poderia explicar o que seu código faz? como ele responde a pergunta? textos ajudam na compreensão.

Comment: Tentei explicar melhor em texto o que tinha no código por comentários... Penso que aqui o que o utilizador pretendia era inicializar um array da estrutura definida inicialmente com um tamanho indicado por o utilizador, e foi isso que coloquei no código... @ErlonCharles

Comment: Alguns pontos a mais são pertinentes para melhorar esta resposta: (i) Arrays de tamanho variável (VLAs, em inglês), só são obrigatórias na especificação de [C99](https://www.dii.uchile.cl/~daespino/files/Iso_C_1999_definition.pdf). Em especificações mais antigas não há previsão para isso na linguagem e, em especificações mais novas, essa funcionalidade é **opcional**. Isso significa que os compiladores podem deixar de aceitar esse comportamento, se hoje o aceitam; (ii) há, também, como resolver o problema utilizando alocação dinâmica de memória, que é a solução mais utilizada

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que as soluções anteriormente propostas funcionem nos maiores compiladores atualmente (testei apenas com `gcc 11.2.0`), mas VLAs (*Variable-Length Arrays*, em tradução livre Vetores de Tamanho Variável) só são obrigatórios na especificação [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). Seu suporte desde [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) é opcional e, portanto, pode haver compiladores que não implementam essa funcionalidade e mesmo os que o fazem podem deixar de fazer.

Uma solução diferente daquelas e que deve funcionar em qualquer compilador C é a que utiliza alocação dinâmica de memória. Ela se baseia em, como o nome sugere, reservar novos espaços na memória ([*heap*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap)), à medida que necessário.

Segue o código exemplo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc / calloc

// É sempre válido definir um limite para a quantidade de elementos que você
// quer armazenar em memória, especialmente quando esse valor vem do usuário,
// de forma a evitar potenciais problemas devido ao mal gerenciamento de
// memória. Para mais informações: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o_din%C3%A2mica_de_mem%C3%B3ria_em_C#Problemas
#define MAX_N_CATEG 10

// Usamos `typedef` para dar um nome ao nosso tipo `struct categoria_st`. Por
// acaso eu defini esse nome como `categoria_st`, mas poderia ter usado qualquer
// outro que não fosse uma palavra reservada da linguagem
typedef struct categoria_st {
  char nome_categ[25];
  int num_subcateg;
  char subcateg_st;
} categoria_st;

int main() {
  int n_categ = 0;
  categoria_st *cat; // Ponteiro para `categoria_st`

  // Para evitar problemas, garantimos que `n_categ`:
  //   - É positivo
  //   - É menor ou igual que `MAX_N_CATEG`
  while (n_categ <= 0 || n_categ > MAX_N_CATEG) {
    printf("Quantas categorias queres adicionar? Escolha um valor entre 1 e %d (0 para sair)\n", MAX_N_CATEG);
    scanf("%d", &n_categ);

    // Damos ao usuário uma forma de sair do programa sem prosseguir
    if (n_categ == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  // Esta é a segunda linha mais relevante do código. Aqui acontece a alocação
  // dinâmica de memória. A função `calloc` pede ao Sistema Operacional uma
  // quantidade de memória livre com espaço suficiente para armazenar `n_categ`
  // elementos do tipo `categoria_st`. Após recebida essa memória, ela é
  // inicializada com `0`. Podemos entender essa segunda etapa como uma
  // "limpeza" do conteúdo anterior naquele espaço de memória que, para o nosso
  // programa, era "lixo" (desnecessário, não fazia sentido).
  //
  // Outro ponto importante é o início da expressão do lado direito da
  // atribuição, `(categoria_st *)`. Esta expressão é usada para fazer uma
  // conversão explícita de tipos. A função `calloc` retorna o tipo `void *`,
  // um ponteiro para `void`. Em poucas palavras, um ponteiro para `void` é,
  // essencialmente, um ponteiro para um endereço de memória específico, sem
  // informação de tipo, e que pode ser atribuído a qualquer tipo de ponteiro.
  // Ao realizar a conversão explícita estamos tirando qualquer margem de dúvida
  // do compilador sobre nossa intenção com essa atribuição: nós queremos um
  // ponteiro para uma região da memória que vai armazenar dados do tipo
  // `categoria_st`.
  //
  // Uma opção diferente seria usar a função `malloc`, com sintaxe similar:
  //   cat = (categoria_st *)malloc(n_categ * sizeof(categoria_st));
  // Note que para a função `malloc` é passado apenas um argumento com o tamanho
  // total de memória desejado. Outra diferença é que a função `malloc` não
  // "limpa" a memória reservada para a nossa variável.
  cat = (categoria_st *)calloc(n_categ, sizeof(categoria_st));

  // Checamos se a memória foi armazenada e entregue ao nosso programa com
  // sucesso. Caso contrário, `cat` terá o valor `NULL`, uma macro definida
  // em diversos cabeçalhos da linguagem, entre eles `stdio.h` e `stdlib.h`,
  // cujo valor, em C, é, normalmente, `((void *)0)` ou `0`. De qualquer forma,
  // seu valor é avaliado como `falso`.
  // Para mais informações sobre `NULL`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL
  if (!cat) {
    printf("Houve um erro ao reservar memória para as categorias.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Aqui vem sua lógica. Você pode usar o operador `[]` pra acessar "posições"
  // diferentes dentro de `cat` de forma análoga a um vetor.
  //
  // Em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91368/76558 há uma comparação bem
  // completa sobre ponteiros e vetores, expondo semelhanças e diferenças.
  for (int i = 0; i < n_categ; ++i) {
    cat[i].num_subcateg = i;
  }

  // Esta é **a linha mais relevante do código**. Um erro muito comum e um
  // grande causador de problemas em códigos com alocação dinâmica de memória
  // é não liberar a memória anteriormente reservada. No limite, isso pode levar
  // a uma falha por falta de memória disponível para o programa ou mesmo a
  // falta de memória para o Sistema Operacional, dependendo do tipo de programa
  // em questão. Liberar memória reservada é imprescindível.
  //
  // Neste caso, como sabemos que, se o programa chegar aqui, `cat` estará
  // apontando para um bloco válido de memória, não inclui a validação. Porém,
  // é boa prática checar se o seu ponteiro aponta para um bloco de memória
  // válido antes de liberá-lo. Isso pode ser feito com:
  //
  //   if (cat) {
  //     free(cat);
  //   }
  //
  // Outro ponto importante é não liberar o mesmo bloco de memória duas vezes.
  // Isso levará a um erro em tempo de execução.
  free(cat);

  return 0;
}
```

Incluí a maior parte da explicação como comentário no código, mas vou deixar as fontes inclusas aqui para mais fácil referência:

- [Informações gerais sobre alocação dinâmica de memória em C](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o_din%C3%A2mica_de_mem%C3%B3ria_em_C#Problemas)
- [Informações sobre `NULL` em C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL)
- [Vetores vs Ponteiros em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91368/76558)