# Quantos case pode usar em um switch?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    char sangue, nome[30];
    printf("Informe nome:\n");
    scanf("%s",& nome);
    printf("Informe o sangue de acordo com a tabela\n");
    printf("|--------+-------+|\n");
    printf("| A (x) | A- (w)  |\n");
    printf("|-------+--------+|\n");
    printf("| B (p) | B- (y)  |\n");
    printf("|-------+--------+|\n");
    printf("| AB (t)| AB- (z) |\n");
    printf("|-------+--------+|\n");
    printf("| O (o) | O- (k)  |\n");
    printf("+-------+---------+\n");
    scanf("%s",& sangue);

    switch(sangue){
        case'x':
            printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e A+");
            break;

        case'w':
            printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e A-");
            break;

        case'p':
            printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e B+");
            break;

        case'y':
            printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e B-");
            break;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Troque scanf("%s",& sangue); por scanf("%c",& sangue); pois é um único caractere e não uma string. E aqui: scanf("%s",& nome); troque por: scanf("%s", nome); pois é uma string. Esta não é a indentação normalmente utilizada em um switch/case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos enumerar os erros e algumas sugestões:

1. O nome não aparece porque você está lendo uma string e salvando num char em `scanf("%s", &sangue)`. Leia o tipo correto, mudando `%s` por `%c` e a variável será preenchida corretamente.
2. No switch você diz ao `prinft` que irá imprimir um string (`%s`) mas não passa nenhuma como parâmetro. O correto seria `printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e A+", nome);`
3. Ao ler o nome da pessoa, seu código não aceitará nomes com espaços. Se a pessoa se chamar "Maria Laura", somente o "maria" será lido. Você pode resolver isso usando um pouco de expressão regular: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &nome);`
4. Agora, como sugestão, para não ficar repetindo a toda hora o texto `"Sr(a) %s seu sangue é"`, você pode imprimir uma vez antes do switch e depois imprimir só tipo sanguíneo, deixando o código mais compacto.
5. Por fim, eu notei que você evita usar acentos no teu código. mas você pode informar ao programa para utilizar os cracteres especiais do português (acentos, ç e formatação de número através da função `setlocale`.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de implementação com as correções e as sugestões acima.

Bons estudos.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>  
//incluímos o header locale.h para utilizar a função setlocale

int main (){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR_utf8"); //daqui pra frente podemos usar acentos
    char sangue, nome[30];
    printf("Informe nome:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &nome);
    printf("Informe o sangue de acordo com a tabela\n");
    printf("|--------+-------+|\n");
    printf("| A (x) | A- (w)  |\n");
    printf("|-------+--------+|\n");
    printf("| B (p) | B- (y)  |\n");
    printf("|-------+--------+|\n");
    printf("| AB (t)| AB- (z) |\n");
    printf("|-------+--------+|\n");
    printf("| O (o) | O- (k)  |\n");
    printf("+-------+---------+\n");

    scanf(" %c", &sangue);      
    printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue é ", nome); 
    switch(sangue){
        case 'x':
            printf("A+\n");
            break;

        case'w':
            printf("A-\n");
            break;

        case'p':
            printf("B+\n");
            break;

        case'y':
            printf("B-\n");
            break;

        case't':
            printf("AB-\n");
            break;  

        case'z':
            printf("AB-\n");
            break;  

        case'o':
            printf("O\n");
            break;

        case'k':
            printf("K-\n");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lucas, como já comentaram, seu scanf da variável sangue está incorreto, pois você precisa pegar um char, corrigindo isso, seu switch já funcionará.

Porém você pode ter problemas por conta do scanf com caracteres, por conta disso, coloquei um exemplo de flush em seu código, a função **flush_in**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void flush_in() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
}

int main (){
    char sangue, nome[30];

    printf("Informe nome:\n");
    scanf("%s", nome);

    flush_in();

    printf("Informe o sangue de acordo com a tabela\n");
    printf("|--------+-------+|\n");
    printf("| A (x) | A- (w)  |\n");
    printf("|-------+--------+|\n");
    printf("| B (p) | B- (y)  |\n");
    printf("|-------+--------+|\n");
    printf("| AB (t)| AB- (z) |\n");
    printf("|-------+--------+|\n");
    printf("| O (o) | O- (k)  |\n");
    printf("+-------+---------+\n");

    scanf("%c", &sangue);

    switch(sangue){
        case'x':
            printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e A+", nome);
            break;

        case'w':
            printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e A-", nome);
            break;

        case'p':
            printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e B+", nome);
            break;

        case'y':
            printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e B-", nome);
            break;

        case't':
            printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e AB", nome);
            break;

        case'z':
            printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e AB-", nome);
            break;

        case'o':
            printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e O", nome);
            break;

        case'k':
            printf("Sr(a) %s seu sangue e O-", nome);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Sr(a) %s, sem sangue encontrado", nome);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Veja mais sobre o flush, nessa pergunta aqui:
[Limpeza do buffer do teclado após scanf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9427/limpeza-do-buffer-do-teclado-ap%C3%B3s-scanf)