# Leitura de CHAR em C que funciona com %s, mas não com %c, por quê? E como funciona o INCREMENTO em um ponteiro?

Tags: c, ponteiro, scanf, buffer

Hospedei o código **completo** no PASTEBIN: https://pastebin.com/feKaxAiz. Se trata de uma matriz onde se é possível realizar a **SOMA** ou **MÉDIA** dos elementos acima da DIAGONAL PRINCIPAL. É um tanto quanto extenso, mas o primeiro problema se encontra no **MAIN**, no scanf de **"OP"**, que referencia a operação que o usuário deseja realizar. Fiz a leitura com **%c** e ele simplesmente **ignora o scanf**, encerrando o programa, porém, se utilizo **%s**, ele permite a leitura de OP e o programa **funciona normalmente**.

```
int main(){
int l, c;
int matriz[MAXL][MAXC];

numLC(&l, &c);
leMatriz(matriz, l, c);
printMatriz(matriz, l, c);

int soma = 0, media, cont = 0;
char OP;

printf("\nescolha uma operacao p/ ser feita com os elementos acima da DIAGONAL PRINCIPAL.\nS = soma | M = media: ");
scanf("%c", &OP);

somaUpDP(matriz, l, c, &soma, &cont);
//printf("\nsoma teste = %d", soma);
//printf("\nnum elementos teste = %d", cont);
operacao(OP, soma, cont);
return 0;
```

Gostaria de uma explicação p/ isso.
Além do mais, gostaria de saber como funciona o **INCREMENTO em um ponteiro**. Na função **somaUpDP** (que realiza a soma dos elementos acima da diagonal principal), utilizo o ponteiro ***cont** para armazenar o tanto de elementos acima da D.P e assim poder realizar a média.

```
void somaUpDP(int matriz[][MAXC], int l, int c, int *soma, int *cont){ //realiza a soma dos elementos ACIMA da DIAGONAL PRINCIPAL.
for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < c; j++){
        if(j > i){
            *soma+=matriz[i][j]; //soma os elementos acima da D.P.
            *cont = *cont + 1; //pega o tanto de elementos acima da D.P (necessário p/ média).
            //*cont++ não funciona (?).
        }
    }
}
```

Tentei fazer a contagem utilizando o operador **++** de incremento na forma ***cont++**, porém não deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

### Vejamos...

São problemas conceituais apenas. O primeiro deles é mais "chatinho": entender a razão que levou a existir o problema em si requer entender bem como funciona o `scanf`. Já o segundo, basta mais atenção que você consegue enxergar tranqüilamente!

---

**1 - SCANF**

O problema relacionado ao `scanf` é comum. Isso **se deve ao** <kbd>ENTER</kbd> **que você pressiona em algum momento prévio** (função `leMatriz(...)`): ele se traduz no caractere `\n`. Como variáveis `char` lêem somente um caractere, o pulo de linha fica no *buffer*. Na leitura seguinte, ele é automaticamente capturado na variável usada pelo `scanf`.

Uma forma simples de contornar isso é usar sempre:

```
scanf("%c\n", &meuChar);
```

Não é a solução mais elegante e não vai funcionar para todas as situações. A melhor forma é usando a função `fgets` ao invés da função `scanf`. O @pmg escreveu uma [resposta elegante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9431/839) com um belo exemplo. Recomendo a leitura.

---

**2 - INCREMENTO DE PONTEIROS**

**Existem prioridades entre operadores**. Por exemplo: `*` e `/` (multiplicação e divisão) possuem prioridade sobre `+` e `-` (soma e subtração).

Em **C**, `++` tem prioridade em relação ao `*` (deferência de ponteiro). Então, se você fizer:

```
*meuPonteiro++;
```

O que ocorre de fato é um incremento do valor dentro do ponteiro. Este valor é o endereço de memória. Assim, você incrementa um neste endereço. Em seguida, ocorre a deferência.

Portanto, "você" não está exatamente lendo o que pensa que está lendo já que acabou mudando o endereço armazenado pelo ponteiro. O modo correto de fazer é:

```
(*meuPonteiro)++;
```

Assim você incrementa o conteúdo no endereço armazenado pelo ponteiro. Os parêntesis são essenciais para definir prioridades.