# erro out of bounds no doctor memory

Tags: c, alocação

Estou tendo um erro de out of bounds no doctor memory, e na hora de imprimir os arquivos . Tem algo errado com esse codigo?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
 char nome[30];
 int idade;
 int altura;
}Pessoa;

int main(void){
    int escolha=1,linhas=1,i=0;
    Pessoa *p;


    for(;;){
            puts("(0) para sair do programa (1) para inserir novo nome \n");
            scanf("%d",&escolha);
            switch(escolha){
            case 1:
                p = (Pessoa *) realloc(p,sizeof(Pessoa*)*linhas);
                 if(!p){
                    puts("nao foi possivel alocar memoria");
                    exit(-1);
                }

                puts("insira o nome da pessoa");
                scanf("%s", p[linhas].nome);
                puts("insira a idade da pessoa");
                scanf("%d", &p[linhas].idade);
                puts("insira a altura da pessoa");
                scanf("%d", &p[linhas].altura);
                linhas++;
                break;
            case 0:

                for(i=1;i<linhas;i++)
                    printf("Pessoa %d nome: %s\tidade: %d\taltura: %d \n", i,p[i].nome,p[i].idade,p[i].altura);
                free(p);
                exit(1);
            default:
                puts("Caractere invalido inserido!");
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
~~Dr.M~~ Error #1: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS beyond heap bounds: writing 0x02a42010-0x02a42014 4 byte(s)
~~Dr.M~~ # 0 msvcrt.dll!ungetwc   +0x595c   (0x7715040c <msvcrt.dll+0x8040c>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 1 msvcrt.dll!scanf     +0x76     (0x77145097 <msvcrt.dll+0x75097>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 2 msvcrt.dll!scanf     +0x17     (0x77145038 <msvcrt.dll+0x75038>)
~~Dr.M~~ # 3 main                  [C:/Users/mathe/Desktop/prob/C/trabalho2/main.c:29]
~~Dr.M~~ Note: @0:00:05.087 in thread 6176
~~Dr.M~~ Note: prev lower malloc:  0x02a41fc8-0x02a41fcc
~~Dr.M~~ Note: instruction: mov    %eax -> (%ecx)
insira a altura da pessoa
```

A saída sai toda corrompida

```
Pessoa 1 nome: Ó"┬      idade: -17891602        altura: -17891602
Pessoa 2 nome: ¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■¯■asdasd   idade: -17891602        altura: -17891602
Pessoa 3 nome: asdasd   idade: 123123   altura: 12312
```

Comment: Vc pode colocar a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Coloquei, também coloquei um exemplo de saída.

Comment: Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perceba esse trecho no seu código:

```
Pessoa *p;
```

Aqui temos um ponteiro, ok. Agora vamos para o `realloc()`:

```
p = (Pessoa *) realloc(p,sizeof(Pessoa*)*linhas);
```

A função `realloc()` vai pegar o endereço de `p` e realocar. A pergunta é: Qual é o endereço de `p`? Eu coloquei o seguinte `printf` para ver qual é o endereço dele:

```
printf("%p \n", p);
```

E obtive essa saída:

> 0x400590

Como pode-se notar, o ponteiro `p` está apontando para um local na memória, então tentar realocar essa parte da memória não é uma boa ideia.

Quando criamos um ponteiro ele vem com um lixo de memória, igual uma variável do tipo `int`.

Você fez esse comentário na outra resposta:

> Eu tinha lido em um forum que o realloc() agia como um malloc() se o ponteiro fosse nulo, ou não alocado, pelo visto não é assim

Mas no caso do seu código o ponteiro `p` não é nulo, ele já aponta para um local de memória e isso gera o erro.

**Solução**

Para resolver o problema basta deixar o ponteiro nulo da seguinte forma:

```
Pessoa *p = NULL
```

Agora sim o ponteiro é `nulo` e o `realloc()` vai ter o mesmo comportamento que o `malloc()`.

Uma dica que te dou é sempre deixar seus ponteiros que não estão em uso apontando para `NULL`, isso pode evitar erros.

Seu programa também tem problemas com [lixo no buffer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9429/219938), coloquei alguns `getchar()` para resolver.

Veja [aqui](https://ideone.com/0k5bI3) seu código funcionando.