# Problema no scanf, loop infinito

Tags: c

Quando eu coloco um char no `scanf` o programa printa um monte de "height" e não me da a chance de escolher outro valor, só entra num loop infinito.

Código:

```
int main()
{
    int result;
  
    while(result < 1 || result > 8)
    {
        printf("height: ");
        scanf("%d", &result);
    }
    
    if(result >= 1 && result <= 8)
    {
        ft_mario(result);
    }
}
```

Já tentei fazer com `char` invés de int e usar o result - '0' mas não deu também, ele não printa dnv quando da errado so para o programa, e tem outro jeito que quantos caracteres eu colocar ele vai dar x quantidades de print de height.

Sei que da para tirar o `if` la e jogar so a função mas também não muda nada.

Como resolvo esse problema ?

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem, mas se você usar vários `scanf("%c", &variavel);` então terá problemas com [lixo no buffer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9427/limpeza-do-buffer-do-teclado-ap%C3%B3s-scanf).

Comment: queria fazer um loop ate o usuario colocar a resposta certa

Comment: No caso um loop que ler `char`, né? Vou fazer um exemplo aqui.

Comment: [Aqui](https://ideone.com/qlSbig) um exemplo usando `char`. Reparei que utilizei `getchar()` para tirar o `\n`  do `buffer`.

Comment: eu entendi oq vc fez mas no caso eu preciso q o usario digite um numero e se caso ele digitar uma letra eu mostro o scanf dnv isso q ta complicando e ainda tem os caracteres especiais ai complica mais pensei em usar a tabela ascii mas tbm n tive sucesso

Comment: Agora entendi o problema, você precisa limpar o `buffer`. Coloque `setbuf(stdin, NULL);` ou uma função customizada depois do `scanf` para limpar o buffer.

Comment: cara fiz isso ai e deu certo agr  o problema é quando coloco mais de um numero ele pega o primeiro numero e ignora oq vem dps e ele era para nao rodar com numero grande so de 1 a 8

Comment: Tem como mandar o código como ele tá agora? Pode fazer uma pergunta com ele sendo um pouco mais claro.

Comment: mal a demora, conseguimos fazer funcionar usando a recriação do setbuf e tbm com fflush amazenando o input em uma variavel( input[50]) e passando ela para um ato,i ae so jogamos na função ela e foi sucesso e com a recriação da função foi de boa tbm, no fim ate o setbuf q tava dando problema funcionou com atoi, vlw mann essa parada de buffer ajudou muito!!!

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que quando faz a leitura de um inteiro pela entrada com `scanf` e não foi possível ler o inteiro, os carateres que digitou ficam na entrada, ou seja no `stdin`. Isso vai fazer com que na próxima tentativa de leitura volte a dar o mesmo erro gerando um loop infinito.

## Interpretar o resultado de `scanf`

A forma mais simples para resolver é testar se não foi possível ler um inteiro pelo retorno do `scanf` e nesse caso consumir um carater da entrada:

```
int main()
{
    int result;

    while(result < 1 || result > 8)
    {
        printf("height: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &result) == 0){ //se scanf deu 0 
            fgetc(stdin); //consome char na entrada
        }
    }

    if(result >= 1 && result <= 8)
    {
        ft_mario(result);
    }
}
```

Nesta solução convém ter em mente que `scanf` devolve a quantidade de entradas lidas para a string especificada. Se apenas tem um `%d` então irá devolver 1 se deu para ler o `%d` ou 0 caso contrário.

O [`fgetc`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/) utilizado apenas está a retirar um caratere do `stdin` sem o utilizar.

## Alternativas

Alternativamente consegue também ler tudo como string para um array de char largo, e verificar se tem apenas números no mesmo. E caso tenha fazer a interpretação à custa de [`atoi`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) ou funções similares, mas para o código que apresenta é mais complicado.

Answer (score 2):

**SEMPRE** teste o retorno de `scanf()`. Veja a documentação. `scanf()` retorna um `int` com o total de especificadores atendidos (especificadores são aquelas coisas que tem um '%' que não seja seguido de outro. No seu caso foi apenas um: `%d`. `scanf()` retorna -1 em caso de erro.

É ingênuo prosseguir com o programa se não leu nada.

`scanf()` foi escrita para ler entrada formatada. Veja o nome: "**scan f**ormatted". O teclado, com 105 teclas de grande liberdade, não é assim o ideal e `scanf()` não devia ser usada para isso. O simples é usar fgets() e ler as linhas, e depois converter para o que precisa.

Se quer algo assim

```
height: teste

height: outro9

height: 898797abcddff3435
8 8 7 7 3 4 3 5
```

(usando todos os valores possíveis) pode usar algo como

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    int     result;
    char    linha[80];
    int     fim = 0;
  
    while(  fim == 0 )
    {
        printf("height: ");
        fgets( linha,sizeof(linha),stdin );
        for ( int i = 0; linha[i] != 0; i+=1 )
        {
            if( linha[i] >= '1' && linha[i] <= '8' )
            {
                printf( "%d ", linha[i] - '0');
                fim = 1;
            }
        };  // for()
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```