# Código não para no scanf em C

Tags: c, loop, input, int, scanf

Estou começando a estudar a linguagem C agora, para aprender mais decidi fazer uma calculadora e estou com dificuldades num input. Aqui está o código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float n1, n2;
    char operador;

    while (1) {
        printf("Digite: <numero> <operador> <numero>\n");
        if (scanf(" %f %c %f ", &n1, &operador, &n2) < 3) {
            printf("Algun valor digitado não coresponde ao seu tipo.\n");
            continue;
        }
            switch (operador)
            {
            case '+':
                printf("%f\n", n1 + n2);
                break;
            case '-':
                printf("%f\n", n1 - n2);
                break;
            case '*':
                printf("%f\n", n1 * n2);
                break;
            case '/':
                printf("%f\n", n1 / n2);
                break;
            default:
                printf("operador invalido!\n");
        }
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Quando algum valor digitado no scanf não corresponde ao seu tipo (por exemplo se eu digitar "a" no n1) o código entra num looping infinito e não é possível digitar mais nada. Já tentei usar o fflush como está acima e colocar um espaço no começo string do scanf, mas não funcionou. Queria saber se alguém pode me ajudar a resolver isso.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` não é portável (pode até funcionar em alguns ambientes, mas não é garantido que funcione em todos - e sinceramente não entendo porque até hoje espalham essa "solução" por aí, mas divago). Enfim, para limpar o buffer, veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9427/112052)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Limpeza do buffer do teclado após scanf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9427/limpeza-do-buffer-do-teclado-ap%c3%b3s-scanf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso ocorre pois `scanf` não consome o `stdin` em caso de erro e `fflush` só funciona para "output streams". Uma das soluções seria usar `fgets` ou um loop de `getchar`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float n1, n2;
    char operador;
    char c;

    while (1) {
        printf("Digite: <numero> <operador> <numero>\n");
        if (scanf("%f %c %f", &n1, &operador, &n2) != 3) {
            // não foi possivel pegar a 3 variavies corretamente
            printf("Algun valor digitado não coresponde ao seu tipo.\n");
            // limpa stdin
            while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
            continue;
        }
            switch (operador)
            {
            case '+':
                printf("%f\n", n1 + n2);
                break;
            case '-':
                printf("%f\n", n1 - n2);
                break;
            case '*':
                printf("%f\n", n1 * n2);
                break;
            case '/':
                printf("%f\n", n1 / n2);
                break;
            default:
                printf("operador invalido!\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

versão com `fgets`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 32

int main()
{
    float n1, n2;
    char operador;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];

    while (1) {
        printf("Digite: <numero> <operador> <numero>\n");
        if (fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, stdin) == NULL)
            // erro ou EOF
            return 1;

        if (sscanf(buf, "%f %c %f", &n1, &operador, &n2) != 3) {
            // não foi possivel pegar a 3 variavies corretamente
            printf("Algun valor digitado não coresponde ao seu tipo.\n");
            continue;
        }
            switch (operador)
            {
            case '+':
                printf("%f\n", n1 + n2);
                break;
            case '-':
                printf("%f\n", n1 - n2);
                break;
            case '*':
                printf("%f\n", n1 * n2);
                break;
            case '/':
                printf("%f\n", n1 / n2);
                break;
            default:
                printf("operador invalido!\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se no código da pergunta aqui `if (scanf(" %f %c %f ", &n1, &operador, &n2) < 3) {` ele fizesse `if (scanf("%f %c %f%*[^\n]", &n1, &operador, &n2)` já não resolveria o problema dele?

Comment: @AugustoVasques O problema é que scanf não consome o stdin quando ocorre algum erro (usuário digitar tipo errado por exemplo). então entraria em loop infinito

Comment: é um ponto válido.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Editei a resposta para ressaltar esse ponto

Comment: Boa resposta. Se puder também colocar uma citação de documentação sobre o ponto do `scanf` não ler `stdin` em casos de erro (fora seus inúmeros problemas) para futura referência, seria ótimo.

Comment: `scanf()` foi escrita para ler dados formatados, como tabelas e em especial arquivos `csv` comuns na época. O teclado não é entrada formatada e essa função está no lugar errado. Não entendi @RuanMontelo o que seria "não ler stdin" e esse lance de inúmeros problemas. O autor apenas errou no uso de `scanf()`... Podia por exemplo só seguir ao ler exatamente os 3 valores

Comment: Obrigado!! Eu acabei usando o getchar porque achei mais simples e deu tudo certo.