# do while repete a tela inicial 2x

Tags: c

Estou tendo problemas com o laço de repetição (provável que seja o `do while`), que está repetindo 2x a tela inicial do meu programa após uma opção "sair" seja selecionada. Estou utilizando **duas funções** e em nenhuma delas existe outro laço `do while` ou `printf` que faça a tela se repetir.

Segue o código principal no qual uso o laço:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "SistemaDeVendas.h"
#include "SistemaDeListagem.h"
#include "Cidades.h"

int main()
{

    FILE *arq;
    arq=fopen("Vendas.txt","a");

    struct listagem{
        char op;
        int outra;
    };

    struct listagem sistema;

    do{
        printf("===========================================\n"
               "ESCOLHA UMA DAS OPCOES:\n"
               "> 0 - SAIR\n"
               "> 1 - VENDAS\n"
               "> 2 - LISTAGEM\n"
               "> 3 - LISTA DE CIDADES\n"
               "===========================================\n");
        scanf("%c", &sistema.op);

        switch(sistema.op){
            case '0':
                printf("Voce escolheu a opcao: SAIR\n\n O sistema esta sendo DESATIVADO...\n\n");
                break;
            case '1':
                printf("Voce escolheu a opcao: VENDAS\n");
                SistemaDeViagem();
                break;
            case '2':
                printf("Voce escolheu a opcao: LISTAGEM\n");
                SistemaDeListagem();
                break;
            case '3':
                printf("Voce escolheu a opcao: LISTA DE CIDADES\n");
                ListaCidades();
                break;
            }
        }while(sistema.op!=0);

    fclose(arq);

    return 0;

}
```

Caso necessitem das funções, posso estar publicando. A tela que se repete é a primeira depois do laço *do*, "ESCOLHA UMA DAS OPCOES".

Comment: O seu `op` é um `char` e `sistema.op!=0` compara um `char` com um `int`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apenas uma inserção do `fflush(stdin);` apos o scanf do menu resolve seu problema.

Isso ocorre por causa que o scanf as vezes mantém um \n, ou até mesmo outra parte da entrada, no buffer temporário de memoria do teclado (stdin) sendo necessário limpá-lo depois do uso do scanf.

Outra forma de resolver o problema seria utilizando a função

```
void limpar_buffer(void)
{
    int c = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
    return;
}
```

ao invés do scanf.

Para saber mais: [click here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9427/222020)
PS: depois que o usuário digitar 0 ( para sair ) é mais comum usar um return, senão irá repetir novamente o menu.